# Unable to debug in vscode

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code, output, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug C code in vscode and when I hit debug, somethings are shown in integrated terminal, debug console but output which I desire is not printed anywhere, for instance output of `printf()` is  nowhere shown, I am trying to take user input using `scanf()` but its not working either.

Comment: Can you please share any image to demonstrate?

Comment: I happened to solve it and have posted an answer to it. Thank You..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I happened to fix my own problem by just trying out different things in the `launch.json` file.
I set the attribute `"externalConsole": true` whose value is by default set to `false`.
Now an external command prompt window opens and output is printed there as well as user input works.
Following is my `launch.json` file:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "gcc.exe build active file"
        }
    ]
}
```